# Simple repository for .Net 2.0

Tags: c#, repository, design-patterns

I am trying to use the repository pattern for a site made in .Net 2.0. All client code is expecting datatable for binding and I am not going to be able to change that, so please bear with me.

I am having a (probably dumb) issue. I cannot figure out how to pass a strongly typed entity to my concrete repository. The interface is forcing me to pass an Employee type but I need to pass a Developer type (it derives from Employee) because it has specific properties not found in the base class.

```
    public interface IEmployeesRepository
    {
        DataTable Employees { get; }
        void SaveEmployee(Employee employee);
        void DeleteEmployee(Employee employee);
    }

    public class DevelopersRepository : IEmployeesRepository
    {             
        public void SaveEmployee(Developer employee)
        {
            Database db = new SqlDatabase(connectionString);
            DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Developers_Insert",   employee.ProgrammingLanguage);
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried using generics instead but then I still will not have a strongly typed object right?

Comment: Can't you just cast the `Employee` back to a `Developer` in the repository implementation?

Comment: Hey, you should dispose your objects. The easiest way to do so is `using` construct.

Comment: Elian - but would the developer properties still be set if I am casting it?

Comment: gaearon - Which objects? I'm using the enterprise library which should handle the lifetime of the database objects on its own, no?

Comment: yes. Casting doesn't change the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be wrong but it sounds like you want to use a generic constraint:

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository<T>
    where T : Employee
{
    DataTable Employees { get; }
    void SaveEmployee(T employee);
    void DeleteEmployee(T employee);
}

public class DevelopersRepository : IEmployeeRepository<Developer>
{             
    public void SaveEmployee(Developer employee)
    {
        Database db = new SqlDatabase(connectionString);
        DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("Developers_Insert",   employee.ProgrammingLanguage);
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DevelopersRepository implements IEmployeesRepository so it must implement all methods in the interface.

```
public void SaveEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    if (!(employee is Developer)) throw new Exception("...");
    ...
}
```

Comment: This would certainly work, I don't like the idea of doing type checks at runtime when you can easily check for those errors during compilation.

Comment: Your use of generics is good, but I assumed from the question that the interface doesn't change.

Comment: The developer's custom properties would not come through this way. The covariance is off.

Comment: @Joe - This has nothing to do with covariance. If you know that the given employee is of type `Developer`, you can always cast it back. You don't lose information when you upcast an object.